# How to have a script tag apply to a certain element, but not others

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, frontend

I am working on a project that requires two angularjs files, textAngular-sanitize and angular-sanitize. When both of these files are loaded in the header or footer, the part of the document that requires the file that is loaded first will work, however the element that requires the file that is loaded after the first ceases to work. I.e when angular-sanitize is loaded first, then the textAngular dependent element stops working, whereas if the textAangular file is loaded first, then the angular-sanitize element stops working. This is presumably because both files are loaded and run over the entire document. Is there a way to confine the 'scope' of one of the files to only one element on the page so that both scripts can be run without interfering with one another?

Or perhaps, is there an alternative method of loading external scripts other than the `<script>` tag?

Here is an example of what is going on:

```
<head ng-app="myApp">
    <script src="scripts/textAngular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
</head>
    <body ng-controller="MainController" ng-init="initialize()">
        <div id="ngSanitizeElement">
            <!-- This element won't work -->
        </div>
        <div id="textAngularSanitizeElement">
            <!-- This element will work -->
        </div>
</body>
```

Comment: this shouldnt happen, unless the 2 override each other. can you make a plunker?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure to understand your problem, but if you're looking for something to load external files from your controllers or your router, try ocLazyLoad : https://oclazyload.readme.io/docs

Answer (score 0):

Which backend do you use? PHP? I would then put in the script tag the value of the right file depending?

Or can't you use 2 different ng-controllers?

```
<div ng-controller="textAngular ">

<div ng-controlelr="angular-sanitize">
```